# situating or discussing, in a sentence

Tags: comparison

> To describe Saint-Saëns’ Piano Quartet in B-flat as a superficial
> imitation of Liszt is to overlook the unique combination of Classical,
> Romantic, and modern elements skillfully woven into the composition.
> ______Saint-Saëns outside of rigid musical traditions allows for a full appreciation of the novelty and wide-ranging mastery demonstrated
> in the work.

This is a sentence from Magoosh GRE, for which an answer for the blank shall be chosen--here, the answer is "situating". But, there is another answer choice "discussing" which I found very attractive. According to Oxford Language (from Google), discuss also means: "talk or write about (a topic) in detail, taking into account different issues or ideas." Following this meaning, the sentence makes perfectly sensible.

I've consulted with its staff and found the explanation non-convincing. Why couldn't one discuss a subject outside/ inside a certain context? Anyone please? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Situating" is just another word for "placing" or "locating".

What they mean here is that they metaphorically place the composer outside a particular set of influences ("music traditions" - presumably the musical traditions within which the composer lived and worked) and discuss him as if he were outside that category.

I think "situating" or "placing" or "locating" is better than discussing, because the physical metaphor makes it clearer that you want to discuss the man's work as if he had written it outside his musical time and place.

Personally, I'd follow the maxim "if it ain't broke, don't fix it" and choose "situating", which seems to fit well with the meaning and register intended by the writer.

As for your question "Why couldn't one discuss a subject outside/ inside a certain context?" I can only say that that's not a linguistic question.

My own question (off the top of my head) would be "How could you ...?" but that's neither here nor there.